# Isn't the variable declared outside with let global variable too?

Tags: function, global, new-operator, var, referenceerror

I am trying to understand new function syntax.

When I declare variable 'value' using let it, I get an error

> ReferenceError: value is not defined

but if I use var or without var the output is printed as test. I assume that the 'value' variable is global because it is defined outside.

But why does it work with var but not let although both are global variable?

```
let value = "test";
    function getFunc() {
        // value = "test";
    
        let func = new Function('console.log(value)');
    
        return func;
    }
    
    getFunc()();
```

Comment: see: [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), and [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). Both documents do contain a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top level, `let`, unlike `var`, does not create a property on the global object.

```
var foo = "Foo";  // globally scoped
let bar = "Bar"; // not allowed to be globally scoped

console.log(window.foo); // Foo
console.log(window.bar); // undefined
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Therefor `let` may only be used inside of an enclosed block denoted by `{}`.